# how to do get mac address info for a single interface on Windows 10?

Tags: windows, networking, windows-10

as title.

I've tried:

- netsh: can't see mac address
- ipconfig: can't see a way of displaying individual interfaces
- getmac: same as ipconfig

Any ideas?

Comment: https://gallery.technet.microsoft.com/scriptcenter/b780c4e4-e986-40a3-9296-65caadd31211

Comment: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/d5fa8998-9da2-413e-9148-bbf1f9aa764a/get-client-macaddress-with-powershell?forum=configmanagersdk

Comment: https://thesurlyadmin.com/2013/05/20/using-powershell-to-get-adapter-information/ What else have you tried?

Answer (score 1):

Sample:

> `C:\> wmic nicconfig get Description,MacAddress
> Description                                     MACAddress
> Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC  40:B8:9A:48:07:21
> Microsoft Kernel Debug Network Adapter
> Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller              68:F7:28:E8:EE:42
> Microsoft ISATAP Adapter
> Bluetooth Device (RFCOMM Protocol TDI)
> Bluetooth Device (Personal Area Network)        40:B8:9A:48:07:22
> Microsoft Wi-Fi Direct Virtual Adapter          42:B8:9A:48:07:21
> Microsoft Teredo Tunneling Adapter`

C:\> **wmic nicconfig Where "Description='Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC'" get Description,MacAddress**
Description                                     MACAddress
Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC  40:B8:9A:48:07:21

C:\> **wmic nicconfig Where "Description='Realtek 8821AE Wireless LAN 802.11ac PCI-E NIC'" get MacAddress /FORMAT:LIST**

MACAddress=40:B8:9A:48:07:21

C:\>

Comment: Other comments seemed designed around using PowerShell.  This answer wasn't.  If you are trying to use PowerShell, the easy thing to do is to run CMD first.  The more complicated method is to place a back-tick (on my keyboard, that's unshifted tilde, to the left of the number 1 and between Tab and Esc) before certain characters including commas, quotation marks, and probably apostrophes.

Comment: any ideas on which property for the "interface name"? Like on ipconfig I see "Ethernet" or "Ethernet 2" and etc. Thanks again

Comment: Yes.  The property is Description.  Notice how I obtained the NIC names in the first command I ran.  I can also see the NIC names with `netstat -nr | more` although, for the question that was asked here, I don't see how that's any better than the sample shown in the answer.